# Amazon S3 - Storing image files from Django - Don't upstream uploaded images by the user

Tags: python, django, image, amazon-s3

I have the custom `User` model in which I've add a `avatar` field

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    # email
    # username
    # first_name
    # last_name   

    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='avatars',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Photo'
    )
```

I've installed the following packages via `pip install`:

```
boto3==1.4.4
django-boto==0.3.11
django-storages==1.5.2
django-storages-redux==1.3.2
Pillow==4.0.0
```

I am using the following Amazon S3 configurations in my `settings.py`

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',

        # Third party apps
        'storages',

]

STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
)

#Amazon S3 Storage
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = get_env_variable('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = get_env_variable('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =  get_env_variable('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

# Tell django-storages that when coming up with the URL for an item in S3 storage, keep # it simple - just use this domain plus the path. 
# (If this isn't set, things get complicated).
# This controls how the `static` template tag from `staticfiles` gets expanded, if you're using it. We also use it in the next setting.
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

# For media files to S3
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'assets'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

I have the `custom_storages.py` where I have some classes to store my static and media files. These clasess are subclassing by `S3BotoStorage`

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

# custom_storages.py 
class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic` my static files are stored in my amazon cloud S3 bucket in the assets directory according to my configuration and that's O.K.

The issue comes when the images are uploaded by the users of my application. More precisely when an user upload their avatar profile.

When an user upload the avatar profile via django admin, all it's works, such as follow:

[image]

And the image is stored in my amazon s3 bucket in the `media/avatars` directory.

[image]

But when an user try upload an image via Django frontend application via `forms.ModelForm` the image is not being upload, such as follow:

[image]

Why in my django admin the image is uploaded, but in my django application frontend via model form the image is not uploaded to S3?

There is something which I am ignoring?

I've these package third application named [django-s3-storage](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage), although I don't tested still

**UPDATE**

According to the comment/answer of [@atn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7645153/htn) my issue was in my html form in where I render the fields forms.

My html template stay of this way:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block title_tag %}Accounts | Settings | iHost {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block body_content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Account Details</h1>
    {% comment %} I've add enctype codification {% endcomment %}

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

However I am intrigued by the second recommendations which [@atn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7645153/htn)
give me:

> 2. Ensure "request.FILES" is included in save method(e.g. form = CustomForm(request.POST, request.FILES

I understand that in some situations, is necessary check or evaluate the request we revceive. This may be in a form definition (forms.py) or in my views when I get the user request. This logic come from the `POST` nature.

What happens to me is that sometimes I get confused when I should evaluate the request in a POST and from what location (form definition or my views)

I know that my question is a newbie question, but I am interested in having some orientation about this.

My forms.py and views.py for that situation are:

My `forms.py`, in which I just customize some fields and nothing more. Is very basic really.

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    speak_languages = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        label='Speak languages',
        widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        choices=User.LANGUAGES_CHOICES,
    )
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'gender':forms.RadioSelect,
            'country_of_origin': CountrySelectWidget(),
            'country_current_residence': CountrySelectWidget(),
            'date_of_birth': DateInput(), #datepicker
        }
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "display_name", "gender",
        "country_of_origin", "city_of_origin", "country_current_residence",
        "city_current_residence", "speak_languages", "phone_number",
        "address", "bio", "avatar", "date_of_birth", "is_student",
        "is_professor", "is_executive", "is_study_host",
        "is_hosting_host", "is_innovation_host", "is_entertainment_host",
        "is_other_services_host", "entertainment_activities",)

        model = get_user_model()
```

And my views.py also is very basic. In her, I just call my model, my form and get the profile user data.

```
class AccountSettingsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    context_object_name = 'preferences'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountSettingsUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_student:
            profile = user.get_student_profile()
            context['userprofile'] = profile
        elif user.is_professor:
            profile = user.get_professor_profile()
            context['userprofile'] = profile
        elif user.is_executive:
            profile = user.get_executive_profile()
            context['userprofile'] = profile
        elif user.is_study_host:
            profile = user.get_study_host_profile()
            context['userprofile'] = profile
        elif user.is_hosting_host:
            profile = user.get_hosting_host_profile()
            context['userprofile'] = profile
        elif user.is_active:
            #profile = user.get_user_profile()
            context['userprofile'] = self.request.user
        return context
```

How can I add some validation type in my views or my forms in case is necessary. How to recognize it, how can I do?

My apologies because is a newbie question.

Comment: Have you checked these two things: 1. Ensure "multipart/form-data" in the form (e.g. <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/abc/">) / 2. Ensure "request.FILES" is included in save method(e.g. form = CustomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

Comment: Also it could be useful to see your form and view code

Comment: @htn I've a new situation with this scenario, and I post the new question about it. I appreciate if you have the time of view my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527277/handle-a-django-imagefield-render-it-into-html-template Best Regards